# Modify the query to get output like this

Tags: sql-server

```
select convert(nvarchar(25),in_gentime, 107) AS LogInDate, 
    convert(nvarchar(25),in_gentime, 108) as LogInTime,
     convert(nvarchar(25),out_gentime, 107) AS LogOutDate,
     convert(nvarchar(25),out_gentime, 108) as LogOutTime  
    from in_time_temp i, out_time_temp o where in_gentime between '10/01/2011 00:01' and '11/18/2011 23:59'
     and i.cardnumber = 'MCL1570' and out_gentime between '10/01/2011 00:01' and '11/18/2011 23:59' and o.cardnumber = 'MCL1570'
     and month(in_gentime) = month(out_gentime) and day(in_gentime) = day(out_gentime) 
    and year(in_gentime) = year(out_gentime) order by year(in_gentime), year(out_gentime),
     month(in_gentime), month(out_gentime), day(in_gentime), day(out_gentime)
```

This query will return like this:

```
Login Date     LoginTime         Logout date     logouttime
Oct 11, 2011    08:06:00    Oct 11, 2011    22:02:00
Oct 12, 2011    08:35:00    Oct 12, 2011    21:14:00
Oct 14, 2011    08:21:00    Oct 14, 2011    21:59:00
Oct 15, 2011    08:21:00    Oct 15, 2011    21:59:00
```

suppose if the record is there for in_time_temp and record is not there for out_time_temp table means it should show output like this....

in this case login in time is there for  Oct 13, 2011 in this in_time_temp but login out time is not available in this out_time_temp

How to modify to get output like this:

```
  Login Date     LoginTime         Logout date     logouttime
    Oct 11, 2011    08:06:00    Oct 11, 2011    22:02:00
    Oct 12, 2011    08:35:00    Oct 12, 2011    21:14:00
    Oct 13, 2011    08:21:00
    Oct 14, 2011    08:21:00    Oct 14, 2011    21:59:00
    Oct 15, 2011    08:21:00    Oct 15, 2011    21:59:00
```

How to modify in my query?

Comment: SQL server is really not intended to do lots of formatting - you should do this in a frontend (app, reporting tool etc.)

Comment: how to do in front end i do no whether the records or inserted or not

Comment: Reporting tool like SQL Server Reporting Services or Crystal Reports often have specific options to *suppress* repeating values ....

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you provide us with the table definition of both `in_time_temp` and `out_time_temp` so that we can work faster. However, while waiting for that, here's another try at it.

The following are my assumptions of the minimum requirements of your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE in_time_temp (
      cardnumber VARCHAR(10)
    , in_gentime DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE out_time_temp (
      cardnumber VARCHAR(10)
    , out_gentime DATETIME
)
```

Here is the code that ought to give you the answer you need.

```
SELECT
  i.cardnumber
, CONVERT(nvarchar(25),in_gentime, 107) AS LogInDate
, CONVERT(nvarchar(25),in_gentime, 108) AS LogInTime
, CONVERT(nvarchar(25),out_gentime, 107) AS LogOutDate
, CONVERT(nvarchar(25),out_gentime, 108) AS LogOutTime
FROM in_time_temp i LEFT OUTER JOIN out_time_temp o 
  ON i.cardnumber = o.cardnumber 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, in_gentime, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, out_gentime, 112)
WHERE 
  i.cardnumber = 'MCL1570' 
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I simplified your query as much as I could.. Please try this out and let us know how it goes.

[more]:
Instead of using the `month`, `day` and `year` functions when (based on your initial SQL code) you only match one day to itself in the `out_time_temp` table (meaning the login and logout **must** occur on the same day), it would be best to take the entire date (just the date, not the time) and use it as your filter. See, I removed the date matchup from the `WHERE` clause and instead included it in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` section since it's also one of your keys for dictating how the JOIN works. Likewise, I did a shortcut at the end (`ORDER BY` clause) but if it doesn't sort the way you want, let me know how.

Comment: ya in this query i didnt get the record Oct13,2011 record which is in the in_time_temp  table..here card number is the common for the both the table where card number is the employee number

Comment: @Nathan :: sorry, i missed that the `o.cardnumber = 'MCL1570'`condition was still in the `WHERE` clause. Can you try again?

Comment: hmm i didnt get the Oct 13,2011 record still

Comment: @Nathan :: I modified my post; hope you can check this... and I hope this will meet your needs :)